# Admob in phonegap / Cordova iOS

Tags: cordova, admob

Can someone help in implementing AdMob in phonegap / Cordova 1.6.1 for iOS?

Note that AdMob is now not allowing to chose "smartphone web", so it's not simply implementing JavaScript code in the index.html. 
Also this tutorial is not working, maybe since it was written for phonegap 1:
http://iphone.keyvisuals.com/iphonedev/implementing-admob-ads-in-a-phonegap-project-for-ios-no-plugins-required/

Thank you!

Comment: Does [this plugin](https://github.com/smithimage/phonegap-plugins/commit/2abbc28605e7266c5a2aadb9eeff51b416eb403a) help at all?

Comment: Tried it now, and nothing happening.
Added the files according to the instructions, no build errors, but I see no ads when I run the app.
Do you know what should I write in the index.html file inorder to make the ad to show?

Comment: did you add '*' to external hosts in PhoneGap.plist? Gonna try it again tomorrow. Ads in PhoneGap seems to be development country, hehe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried [this](https://github.com/smithimage/phonegap-plugins/blob/master/iPhone/AdMob/) again it it actually did work. (With phonegap 1.3 xCode 4.2)

I added the lastest SDK like [so](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/ios/fundamentals?) .

The I added NSLogs to all AdMob contoller function to see whats going on.

I called the js function createBanner({"siteId":"your-id"})

loadBanner()

and (that was the really stupid part)

moveBanner({"positionX":0,'positionY':0})

in the appropriate callback.

Ah, and if you get some error that says sth. about linking, just do whats described in the xcode error log.

PS: And don't forget that '*' in PhoneGap.plist

That's it

Comment: Not sure what I'm doing wrong. Added .h and .m files, added .js and called it, added * and an entry for the plugin in .plist, using this call: window.plugins.adMob.createBanner({"siteId":"******"}); and getting this error 'window.plugins.adMob' [undefined] is not an object. Any idea what i'm missing?

Comment: all right - i got it! Few changes needed in the .js file - Change every call from "phonegap" to "cordova"

Comment: After getting this to work on XCode, when testing it on a device it's not working. I get: Xcode could not locate source file: GADNetworkChecker.m. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Yes, sounds familiar. Guess you need to add some linking flags. Click your 'App->Targets->Build Settings->Linking->Other Linking flags' and add "-ObjC -all_load" to your linking flags. That fixed it in my case.

Comment: I've added "-ObjC -all_load" and the app still crash on the device. What am I missing? Can it be something with the configuration settings?

Comment: BTW, I've added NSLog to all of the functions as you did, and I see that each of the 3 calls (createBanner, loadBanner, moveBanner) is ending successfully

Comment: hmmm, clean the project and build it again? What iDevice are you using? It's running on my iPad2 5.0 as a pure iPhone app. What version of the SDK are you using. I have 6.0.1

Comment: Tried to clean and run. No help. I'm using sdk 4.2, with iPhone 3GS as the device.

Comment: From reading a bit on the web, I get that this is a linking problem to the AdMob SDK folder, which as you suggested should be solved by "-all_load". I read that I can use "-force_load", but what is the path I should write right after it?

Comment: Probably the path of the GoogleAdMobSDK. Why don't you drop 4.2 and install 6.0.1 of GoogleAdmobSDK? Otherwise i'm running out of ideas.. are there any settzing errors, compiler warnings, error messsages?

Comment: The GoogleAdmobSDK is in the same folder as the .xproj file. I'm now upgrading to XCode 4, the transfer is not ao slick... :)

Comment: All right! I got it. Installed the new XCode, using iOS 5.1 and it is working. One last thing: How can I remove the alerts that are popping ("Display banner", "will leave application", "banner removed")?

Comment: Found the alerts in Admob.js. Jusn need to comment these lines out.